# Page does not exist build error in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I have done a fresh install of VS2015 Community with Xamarin. I created a xaml page in the portable project. Then I see the most common error people have been cribbing about, `InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context`. A lot of solutions have been suggest by people.

Finally what worked was changing the build property of my Hellopage.cs to Embedded resource. But once that is done in the App.cs where you set the Mainpage, I see red squiggly lines which say that my Hellopage does not exist?
This is how I'm trying to set the mainpage.

```
MainPage = new Hellopage();
```

Anything that I'm missing?

[Worked Solution Link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68679/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before and the reason was that the XAML files weren't processed correctly. What you should try is this:

1. In the properties pane of Hellopage.xaml, see Custom Tools
2. Change the value to MSBuild:Compile or something else
3. Click around to make sure Visual Studio processes the change
4. Change the value back to MSBuild: UpdateDesignTimeXaml

Another thing you can try is open the xaml and xaml.cs files and save them.

Comment: This is what fixed it. I can't believe that you didn't have a single UpVote when I read this. Now you have mine.